# Using variable as 'id' attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jaggery-js

I have following jaggery code for UI where I am fetching values from user via UI.

```
<%
for (i = 0; i < applicationAttributes.length; i++) {
%>
<div>
  <label>data:</label>
  <div>
      <input type="text" id = "attribute_<%= i%>" >
  </div>
</div>
<%
}
%>
```

when reading the values respective to each ids,

```
var data = $("#attribute_1").val();
```

But it is not returning the value, Can someone specify the proper method to assign 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no space between `id` and its value

```
<input type="text" id = "attribute_<%= i%>" >
<!- _________________^_^ -->
```

It should be

```
<input type="text" id="attribute_<%= i%>" />
```

And it's a good practice to have `/` closing void elements.

Comment: `/` is obsolete in html5.

Comment: @GottZ, I have to use those in my JSX files.

Comment: What browser or framework disallows a space on id attributes? It works with a space in both react, jquery, and plain html.

Comment: i see. well i'm a glimmer.js user so.. i go with the html5 spec

Comment: @GottZ JSX isn’t HTML; tags must be closed. IMO that’s a better approach anyway. HTML 5 doesn’t disallow closing tags: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags

Comment: Re: attribute assignment spacing, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes

Comment: @AdamAzad Yes it works, Thanks. If I am retrieving inside loop, I tried like : $("#attribute_" + i ) where i is the iterator. But it returns null only. :( what could be the reason?

Comment: @user3686193, could you post where/when you're selecting the element? The code might be executed before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: html5 says auto closing tags should not be closed. auto closing tags are tags like textarea or input wich don't have a true innerHTML property. it does not say there is nothing that should be closed. if you use webcomponents you are highly likely writing them in a self closing style in case you don't want the web component to yield a body. you are confusing auto closing tags with components here.